# How to get selector working in redux-form app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, selector, redux-form

I am a react newbie and trying to use selectors in my redux-form app. Here is a simplified sample(the original form contains tens of calculations and fields). It takes sums 2 amounts from the form and returns it:

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
import { sum } from "../calculations";

const sumAmounts = state =>{
    debugger
    if (!state) return;

    if (!state.amount1 || !state.amount2)
  return  sum(state.amount1,state.amount2);
};
export default createSelector(
    sumAmounts
);
```

When I run my Form it does not call the sumAmounts:

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import sumAmounts from "../selectors/sumSelector";

export class FormContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Field
          name="amount1"
          type="number"
          component="input"
          label="Amount 1"
        />
        <Field
          name="amount2"
          type="number"
          component="input"
          label="Amount 1"
        />
        <Field
          name="amount3"
          type="number"
          component="input"
          label="Amount 3"
        />
        <Field
          name="amount4"
          type="number"
          component="input"
          label="Amount 4"
        />
        <Field
          name="amount4"
          type="number"
          component="label"
          label={this.props.sum}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

FormContainer = reduxForm({
  form: "myForm" // a unique identifier for this form
})(FormContainer);

const selector = formValueSelector("myForm");

FormContainer = connect(state => {
  const amount1 = selector(state, "amount1");
  const amount2 = selector(state, "amount2");
  const sum = sumAmounts(amount1, amount2);
  return { amount1, amount2, sum };
})(FormContainer);

export default FormContainer;
```

How can I make sure it is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sumAmounts` is not a selector, you are invoking it using 2 parameters (`sumAmounts(amount1, amount2)`) but it only has one parameter `state`.

In your `mapstatetoprops` you are already extracting the state props you need to calculate the sum, namely `amount1` and  `amount2` so why not calculating the sum there instead of going through other selectors?

```
  const amount1 = selector(state, "amount1");
  const amount2 = selector(state, "amount2");
  const sum = +amount1 + +amount2;
  console.log("map state to props " , amount1, amount2, sum);
  return { amount1, amount2, sum };
```

Comment: Like I said I got calculations I want to reuse hence the selector design. Is it possible to have to calculation in the selector?